# How can I formulate mathematical constraints in such case?

Tags: constraint-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Problem:

I have batch size, which is m <= batch size <= M , and some numbers of orders, then I want to sequence the orders with satisfy the batch size constraints.

For example, batch size = 4, and I have 15 orders, like: A types--9  B types---6
and if I sequence the orders, maybe:

[A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A]   or

[A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A],

Now, I want to formulate a constraints such as(likely integer constraint):

if x_{i} = 1  then x_{i+1}=x_{i+2}=...=x_{i+4} = 1 where x_{i} \in {0,1}

but I don't know how determine the index set of x.

Could you help me?

Comment: I use such formulate:   for k in range(K-batch size):   if x_{i}=1 then x_{i+1} = ...=x_{i+batch size - 1} = 1    but this is not exactly.

Comment: What solver are you using?

Comment: Now, I'm using SCIP.

Comment: I would approach this through *automata* and *network-flow* like modelling. Except your real-world data is much bigger because we basically would build a layered-graph (sequence-length * state-cardinality). Maybe check out: `Côté, Marie-Claude, Bernard Gendron, and Louis-Martin Rousseau. "Modeling the regular constraint with integer programming." International Conference on Integration of Artificial Intelligence (AI) and Operations Research (OR) Techniques in Constraint Programming. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2007.`